# Jenkins Pipeline builds self checkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a simple build release pipeline setup for a maven project:

```
checkout scm
sh 'mvn -B release:prepare release:perform'
```

The jenkins SCM polling is enabled. When release is done, an scm commit is made with the next version in the pom.xml file.

Because of the polling, the jenkins builds start again.

How do I disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have to be done in the `Jenkinsfile` using check for e.g. last commit message:

```
checkout scm
sh `git log --format=%s -1 > last-message`
lastMessage = readFile('last-message').trim()
if (lastMessage.startsWith('[maven-release-plugin]') {
    return
}
```

Comment: This seems hacky, but solved my problem. There needs a better solution than this.